# Package migration from version 3 to version 8 failed with error 0x80004003 "Invalid pointer" error

Tags: ssis

I've been running into a boatload of issues when attempting to run a Master package via dtexecui.exe and also within BIDS. I'm not sure what's causing it, as I haven't made any changes to any versions. It appears to be erroring out on random child packages, so it's difficult to pinpoint what the cause is. The individual child packages run fine themselves, using dtexecui and within BIDS. I've tried reimporting the previous version of the Master package from our source control software and saving it to the solution file, but no good, as the errors persist. I've also tried recreating the file connection managers to the child packages that are erroring out, but that didn't fix it either. Here are the errors that are occurring from our error log table for ssis packages:

```
> Beginning of package execution. There was an exception migrating the
> package from version 3 to version 8. Exception information follows.
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object.    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSInfoEvents100.FireInformation(Int32
> InformationCode, String SubComponent, String Description, String
> HelpFile, Int32 HelpContext, Boolean& pbFireAgain)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageFormatUpdate.VersionUpdate.LogUpgradeStepInfo(Int32
> code, String msg)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageFormatUpdate.VersionUpdate.VersionUpdate3or4to5()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageFormatUpdate.VersionUpdate.UpdateVersion(Int32
> packageVersion, Int32 targetVersion, IDTSInfoEvents100 infoEvents,
> String& xmlDocument, String packagePassword,
> DTS_PACKAGE_UPGRADE_OPTIONS packageUpgradeOptions) There was an
> exception migrating the package from version 3 to version 8. Exception
> information follows. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object.    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSInfoEvents100.FireInformation(Int32
> InformationCode, String SubComponent, String Description, String
> HelpFile, Int32 HelpContext, Boolean& pbFireAgain)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageFormatUpdate.VersionUpdate.LogUpgradeStepInfo(Int32
> code, String msg)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageFormatUpdate.VersionUpdate.VersionUpdate3or4to5()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageFormatUpdate.VersionUpdate.UpdateVersion(Int32
> packageVersion, Int32 targetVersion, IDTSInfoEvents100 infoEvents,
> String& xmlDocument, String packagePassword,
> DTS_PACKAGE_UPGRADE_OPTIONS packageUpgradeOptions) Package migration
> module has failed. Package migration module has failed. Package
> migration from version 3 to version 8 failed with error 0x80004003
> "Invalid pointer". Package migration from version 3 to version 8
> failed with error 0x80004003 "Invalid pointer". Error loading value
> "<DTS:Property xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
> DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">3</DTS:Property>" from node
> "DTS:Property". Error loading value "<DTS:Property
> xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
> DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">3</DTS:Property>" from node
> "DTS:Property". Error 0x80004003 while loading package file
> "D:\SFAS\SSIS\SESDatamart\packages\Load_DimProduct.dtsx". Invalid
> pointer . Error 0x80004003 while loading package file
> "D:\SFAS\SSIS\SESDatamart\packages\Load_DimProduct.dtsx". Invalid
> pointer . End of package execution.
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated, as I've been banging my head over this for a while and it's been preventing me to deploy to the higher environments. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did it happen? Did you try to change sql server version? Did you upgrade the packages?

Comment: Hi Prabhat. All I did was update queries in 2 child packages. I don't think this should be causing any issues. Your thoughts, please?

Comment: somehow development environment and production aren't in sync. Your best bet is, re-open the solution in SSDT, re-compile and deploy again.

Comment: Thanks, Prabhat, but I've tried rebuilding the solution, but no good. Any other suggestions would be welcome, please. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. I am out of thoughts. Rebuilding with correct version should have done the trick